# Dispersion in a rectangular prism

Tags: visible-light, refraction

Why are the colours visible only at the fringes of the light refracted through a rectangular prism?

[image: dispersion]

Comment: Can you include a photo or a link to a photo showing what you mean by "visible only at the fringes of the light"

Comment: I agree, it is unclear what you are asking at the moment.  Adding a photo would be helpful.

Comment: There is a diagram here but the explanation doesn't explain the white light between the fringes. http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refrn/Lesson-4/Dispersion-of-Light-by-Prisms

Answer (score -1):

White light is not light of a specific colour but the superposition of light rays of a range of different colours.  The white light beam is comprised of a reasonably uniform distribution of frequencies across the visible spectrum that are also reasonably uniformly distributed  spatially across the width of the beam.  As the white beam is refracted the comprising rays are also refracted at varying angles depending on their frequency.  This creates a blue and red fringe at the edges of the refracted beam.  If the refracted beam was projected onto a screen sufficiently far enough away, then the white light in the centre of the refracted beam would resolve into regions of all the colours of the rainbow between red and blue.  Since this distance would have to be very great for incident beams of visible diameter, the other colours of the rainbow simply "mix" to form white light.

Comment: The article you link to does explain why there is a red fringe at the top (which is where the light is bent least in that particular set up) and blue at the bottom.  I'm not convinced by your remark about what would happen if the image were projected onto a distant scree, since at any point (other than the edge) the various colours of the spectrum would be overlapping.